# Implicit conversion from enumeration type with Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I just updated to Xcode 6 and got an warning message that I cannot solve. I have been searching for an answer for hours, but no luck. The warning and the code line are below. Has anyone else had this problem?

**Warning**

Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSURLCacheStoragePolicy' to different enumeration type 'NSURLRequestCachePolicy' (aka 'enum NSURLRequestCachePolicy')

**Code**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:geocodeUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:10.0];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docs say `cachePolicy:` should be one of `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`, `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`, `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`, or `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad`.  The value you're passing to it is defined for responses rather than requests.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I just set the cachePolicy = 0, and that fixed the issue. I could also use cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData. I have added both values in case others run into this issue as well.